# Basic yet thorough assembly tutorial (linux)?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I want to learn some practical assembly language having just learned the basic concepts in class. Are there any decent books or tutorials (nasm, etc) that would be recommended?

Comment: I didn't like either of the top 2 linked tutorials, and the 3rd link is a link to this post. While I find keyword advise helpful, linking to Google directly like that can be extremely annoying for people that found this page via google.

Answer (score 26):

[PC Assembly Language](http://pacman128.github.io/pcasm/) is my favorite resource on assembly programming. It's modern, free, and covers a variety of topics. It uses [NASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netwide_Assembler) and the examples are available for Linux (among several other systems).

Answer (score 8):

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly

Answer (score 7):

I agree that PC Assembly Language is very good.  Other good ones using GAS are:

- [Programming from the Ground Up.](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/)
- [Professional Assembly Language, Blum](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764579010)

Comment: Professional Assembly Language is a great book, I recommend it, too

Answer (score 3):

"what is the point in learning assembly just for the heck of it? "

Because you get to learn HOW the CPU works and get a better understanding of the system.  I would say understanding assembler is in itself practical.

Answer (score 2):

- http://www.duntemann.com/assembly.html

I recommend Jeff Duntemann's Assembly Language Step By Step, Third Edition.  It was my first introduction to asm, but is nice and readable and fairly modern and up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the official Intel manuals. You can request the hard copy on Intel's website.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#External_links

```
* Intel 64 and IA-32 Software Developer Manuals
* AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual Volume 1: Application Programming (PDF)
* AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual Volume 2: System Programming (PDF)
* AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual Volume 3: General-Purpose and System Instructions (PDF)
* AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual Volume 4: 128-Bit Media Instructions (PDF)
* AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual Volume 5: 64-Bit Media and x87 Floating-Point Instructions (PDF)
```

Some resources from my personal friend, [Google](http://www.google.com):

- Function calling convention:

> http://unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html
>
> http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/asm/calling.html

- Brief tutorial

> http://www.csn.ul.ie/~darkstar/assembler/

- Using SSE

> http://www.neilkemp.us/v4/articles/sse_tutorial/sse_tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the assembly tutorials page at http://pickatutorial.com

I hope it helps.