# Can't we just write a program in machine level language?

Tags: bios, systems-programming

Compiler convert human understandable language into machine level language. Can't we just write a program in machine level language so that it will be easy and quick for a program to execute.

Comment: Just realised this question has nothing to do with Unix & Linux, I haven't the authority to mark it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can program in assembler under Linux.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836946/basic-yet-thorough-assembly-tutorial-linux) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721583/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-x86-assembly-on-a-linux-platform) questions on Stack Overflow, for example. Also, the [Linux Assembly HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/Assembly-HOWTO.pdf) looks good.

Comment: Technically, asm is one small step removed from actual machine code.

Answer (score 1):

> Compiler convert human understandable language into machine level language. Can't we just write a program in machine level language so that it will be easy and quick for a program to execute.

**No one writes programs in machine language.**  Normal binary exectuables are *not* just machine code anyway, so it would be pointless to try and do this.  Binaries contain machine code but include specific, OS dependent formatting.  For example, linux uses [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).  This format is understood by the [linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) and [loader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_%28computing%29) (on *nix, the loader is part of the kernel). The only place unadulterated machine code exists is in the system memory.

You can write programs in *assembly language*, which is very similar to machine language, but then this must be compiled and linked.  In other words, it is the same thing as writing a program in any other compiled language.

Finally, creating a binary manually by formatting some machine code would not provide any advantages and it would be an endless headache to work with.  You might do it as a learning excercise, but not for any real purpose.

Comment: Then how are compilers built so that they can communicate with machine level language. There must be some language.

Comment: Because compilers are themselves compiled.  They run as machine code in memory executed through the processor, just like *EVERY* other process.  That's the significance of machine code.  It is the only thing that actually runs on the hardware.

Comment: The very first compilers were written in assembly. Since then, compilers usually compile themselves, and when ported to a new machine, we use cross compilation: teach a compiler how to write code for a new machine, then compile the compiler with that. This is how C is brought to new machines. And then, most high level languages themselves are written in C. Eg, python, java, perl, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but then you have to write more and then it takes longer, so using a higher level language and compiler is more efficient on your time. More often than not, a compiler is better than what a mere human can do (they are pretty good programmers these compiler writers).

Comment: I just asked this so i can know how all this programing language got evolved from null to this level. I still wonder how coding is done in this piece of solid.

Comment: Programming languages / instructions sets are designed *before* the machines that run them, and one definition of "computer" is a machine that can execute a *Turing complete* language (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).  This concept is what has made the evolution of higher level languages possible -- ponder the 3rd paragraph: *"the terms 'Turing complete' or 'Turing equivalent' are used to mean that **any real-world general-purpose computer or computer language can approximately simulate any other real-world general-purpose computer or computer language.**"*

Comment: Since any Turing complete language (such as asm or machine code) can be used to simulate any other turing complete language (nb: they all are, by design, Turing complete), you can compile C code into assembly and assembly into machine code, etc.